# How to extract elements from a list with specific features

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape a Wuzzuf website and I want to scrape job skills with this code:

```
result = requests.get("https://wuzzuf.net/search/jobs/?q=data+analysis&a=navbl")
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
job_skills = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "css-y4udm8"})
```

But instead it returns all the information from the division. And I want the elements with `<a>` tags from the same `div` with `class = "css-y4udm8"`.

Comment: Use `find_all("a", class_="css-y4udm8")`?

Comment: maybe you should run `for`-loop and for every element from list `job_skills` you should run another `find("a")` or `find_all("a")`

Answer (score 0):

*Without more details and expected output it is not that easy to give an explicit answer, so improving your question would be great.*

Assuming that the skills are represented by the single list items with dot as prefix, you could use the following selection to extract unique skills:

```
set(soup.select('div.css-y4udm8 a:-soup-contains("· ")'))
```

If you like to get also the other `<a>` in the `<div>` just go with:

```
set(soup.select('div.css-y4udm8 a'))
```

---

Alternative would be to store text and url in dict:

```
{a['href']:a.text.replace(' · ','') for a in soup.select('div.css-y4udm8 a')}
```

Output:

```
{'/a/Full-Time-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Full Time', '/a/Experienced-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Experienced', '/a/Analyst-Research-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Analyst/Research', '/a/Sales-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Sales', '/a/Analysis-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Analysis', '/a/CRM-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'CRM', '/a/Data-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Data', '/a/Data-Analysis-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Data Analysis', '/a/Microsoft-Office-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Microsoft Office', '/a/Sales-Target-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Sales Target', '/a/Sales-Skills-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Sales Skills', '/a/IT-Software-Development-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'IT/Software Development', '/a/Engineering-Telecom-Technology-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Engineering - Telecom/Technology', '/a/Insurance-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Insurance', '/a/Retail-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Retail', '/a/Computer-Science-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Computer Science', '/a/Information-Technology-IT-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Information Technology (IT)', '/a/Analyze-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Analyze', '/a/English-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'English', '/a/Data-Analytics-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Data Analytics', '/a/Manager-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Manager', '/a/Quality-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Quality', '/a/SQL-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'SQL', '/a/ETL-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'ETL', '/a/Microsoft-SQL-Server-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Microsoft SQL Server', '/a/Data-Developer-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Data Developer', '/a/Data-Stage-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Data Stage', '/a/Accounting-Finance-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Accounting/Finance', '/a/Analyst-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Analyst', '/a/Data-Analyst-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Data Analyst', '/a/Relational-Databases-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Relational Databases', '/a/Software-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Software', '/a/Entry-Level-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Entry Level', '/a/Customer-Service-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Customer Service', '/a/Marketing-PR-Advertising-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Marketing/PR/Advertising', '/a/Microsoft-PowerPoint-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Microsoft PowerPoint', '/a/Microsoft-Outlook-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Microsoft Outlook', '/a/Microsoft-Word-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Microsoft Word', '/a/After-Sales-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'After Sales', '/a/Electronics-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Electronics', '/a/Software-Development-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Software Development', '/a/Python-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Python', '/a/Big-Data-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Big Data', '/a/Logistics-Supply-Chain-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Logistics/Supply Chain', '/a/Power-BI-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Power BI', '/a/Tableau-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Tableau', '/a/Economics-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Economics', '/a/Business-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'business', '/a/Statistics-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Statistics', '/a/Reporting-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Reporting', '/a/Database-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Database', '/a/Analytical-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'analytical', '/a/Communication-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Communication', '/a/Communication-Skills-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Communication skills', '/a/Engineering-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Engineering', '/a/Programming-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Programming', '/a/Engineering-Mechanical-Electrical-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Engineering - Mechanical/Electrical', '/a/Electrical-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Electrical', '/a/Computer-Engineering-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Computer Engineering', '/a/Microsoft-Excel-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Microsoft Excel', '/a/Data-Entry-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Data Entry', '/a/Microsoft-Power-BI-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Microsoft Power BI', '/a/Business-Analysis-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Business Analysis', '/a/BI-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'BI', '/a/Computer-Skills-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Computer Skills', '/a/Administration-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Administration', '/a/Big-Data-Analytics-Jobs-in-Egypt': 'Big Data Analytics'}
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

result = requests.get("https://wuzzuf.net/search/jobs/?q=data+analysis&a=navbl")
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src)
skills = set(a.text.replace(' · ','') for a in soup.select('div.css-y4udm8 a:-soup-contains("· ")'))
skills
```

##### Output

```
{'analytical', 'English', 'Statistics', 'Engineering', 'Information Technology (IT)', 'Reporting', 'Accounting/Finance', 'Computer Skills', 'CRM', 'SQL', 'Microsoft SQL Server', 'business', 'Sales', 'Microsoft Office', 'Tableau', 'Marketing/PR/Advertising', 'Analyst', 'Software', 'Microsoft Excel', 'BI', 'Analyst/Research', 'Engineering - Mechanical/Electrical', 'Electrical', 'IT/Software Development', 'Retail', 'Computer Science', 'Communication', 'Engineering - Telecom/Technology', 'Sales Target', 'Sales/Retail', 'Analyze', 'Logistics/Supply Chain', 'Microsoft PowerPoint', 'Communication skills', 'After Sales', 'Customer Service', 'Electronics', 'Economics', 'Customer Service/Support', 'Microsoft Word', 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Python', 'Sales Skills', 'Quality', 'Programming', 'Microsoft Power BI', 'Administration', 'Computer Engineering', 'Power BI', 'ETL', 'Software Development', 'Insurance'}
```